# Let $R=\mathbb{Z}[i]/(3+i)$. Why is this a ring and show that $|R|=10$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R=\mathbb{Z}[i]/(3+i)$. Why is this a ring and show that $|R|=10$. I'm not allowed to use isomorphisms for the second bit.

For the first bit I said $(3+i)$ is an ideal, $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is a ring, and $\mathbb{Z}[i]/(3+i)$ is a quotient group so it is a ring.

Second bit no idea.

Comment: Think of this as polynomials with integer coefficients which then get evaluated at the complex number i. Why is i^3 equal to -i equal to 3 in this ring?

Comment: We have $i^3=-i$ but why $=3$?

Comment: What is the equivalence class of $3+i$?

Comment: $R=(3+i)+r $where $r$ is in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$. If $3=-i$ then $a+bi=a-b(3)=a-3b$?

Comment: When you quotient out by something you are effectively treating that "thing" as "zero". In other words, $\mathbb{Z}[i]/(3+i)$ is the structure you get by taking $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ and imposing $3+i=0$.

Comment: I think $(3+i)$ is an ideal, does it still mean only $3+i=0$?

Comment: Ok but how does this all help  show $|R|=10$?

Comment: No answer on there

Comment: $10=0$ and $i=7$, by squaring. Can you see that this leaves us with only $10$ distinct elements?

Comment: I get $3=-i$ but why is $10=0$?

Comment: $9=-1$ so add $1$ to each side?

Comment: Still don't see why there are only 10 distinct elements.

Comment: Nope it is in my lecture notes. Just states that it is a ring and $|R|=10$ so I was wondering why.

Comment: The only distinct elements are $0$ to $9$. But what about the imaginary parts

Comment: Remember, in this ring $i=-3$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like to think of a quotient thing as we keep everything but modify the *equality* on the given structure. 
 So, things like (some ring)$/(a-b)$ translate to [$a=b$  in the new structure].

Now, the original structure is $\Bbb Z[i]$, the Gaussian integers.

Then we modify the equality so that it respects the structure ($+,-,\cdot$), by posing $3=-i$.

In the new structure therefore every Gaussian integer $a+bi$ will be equal to the *integer* $a-3b$.

We get the integers $0,1,2,\dots,9$, and, as $3^2=(-i)^2$, we have $10=0$.

Now the only thing left to prove is that these ten numbers are still different in the quotient ring.

Comment: Btw, observe that $(3-i)\overline{(3-i)}=3^2+1^2=10$.